# Copy oldstyle numbers from pdf (Minion Pro)

Tags: luatex, fontspec, copy-paste, oldstylenums

I can't get LuaLaTeX (0.76.0-2013061707, current TeXLive) to produce a pdf with copyable (in adobe reader) oldstyle numbers with the Minion Pro font.

I tried the method [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/74760/how-do-i-customize-a-lualatex-cmap/76356#76356), but I get the error

> that font has been accessed already, changing it is forbidden

I don't like using accsupp, as I would have to use a macro everytime a number is used.

My test code is here:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\defaultfontfeatures{Numbers=OldStyle}
\setmainfont{Minion Pro}
\begin{document}
1234567890
\end{document}
```

Comment: Works here; the string copied and pasted from the pdf output is ````

Comment: @phg but Juri probably wants 1234567890. As far as I can see it works with context (at least with another font), so the code is there. One only needs to find it ...

Comment: I have also noticed this with the libertine fonts. It's behaviour is new from texlive 2013, and is also observable with small caps and other stylistic features. It also seems to be a font spec issue rather then lualatex as ex latex behaves the same way.

Comment: @ulrike-fischer can you show your Context code? With ``\starttext \feature[+][just-os] 0123456789 \stoptext`` I see exactly the same behavior as with luaotfload.

Comment: I used `\font\test={name:Cambria:script=latn;language=DFLT;onum=true}
\test 12345`. In context this gives me copyable numbers, but with lualatex not. I don't know the high level commands necessary in context.

Comment: I think it worked with older versions of lualatex (and packages) but I'm not sure..

Comment: @phg: Addition it worked for my test case in TL 2012.

Comment: @ulrike-fischer Looks like a regression in the font loader. The same applies to smallcaps: ````.

Comment: [Reported](http://www.ntg.nl/pipermail/ntg-context/2013/074349.html).

Comment: @phg: Does only the highlevel command `\feature` break for you or also the low-level "font with +onum"? For me both works fine. I ran an context update yesterday (`ConTeXt  ver: 2013.08.01 01:31 MKIV beta`) but the low-level version worked also before. With luoatload the low-level version doesn't work (=doesn't copy correctly).

Comment: @ulrike-fischer add ``mode=node`` which is the default in Luaotfload.

Comment: With `mode=node` I get neither old style numbers nor small caps in context. In lualatex I get the correct glyphs but they are not copyable. With `mode=base` everything is fine in both systems. Doesn't context has an "auto mode"? Perhaps this can explain the different results in the mailing list.

Comment: @phg: I correct my previous comment. Now mode=node gives with context the correct glyphs too (and they are copyable). I have no idea what changed in between - perhaps some test recreated a cache.

Comment: Fixed in next luaotfload; turns out Hans repaired it two weeks ago.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a now-fixed bug.