# Fontspec package creates composite character that consists of a separate symbol and accent

Tags: xetex, luatex, fontspec, unicode

I have simple code, which have strange behavior. When I compile this code by command `lualatex test.tex` or `xelatex test.tex` and look into the generated pdf file, the **glyphs with accents** are two symbols in reality.

```
 \documentclass{scrbook}
 \usepackage{fontspec} 
 \setmainfont{Cambria}  

 \begin{document}
   Příliš žluťoučký kůň úpěl ďábelské ódy.
 \end{document}
```

As a result, I cannot search copied text properly, between source file with UTF encoding and pdf file. The text is simply not the same. I was hoping that if I was going to use UTF, I would avoid this phenomenon.

I use up to date Miktex distribution together with MS Visual Studio Code as editor with UTF setting.

Comment: That's a problem specific to cambria. See https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/420568/2388. (char+accent is an allowed decomposition also in unicode: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_equivalence).

Comment: Are you sure alle the accented letters exists in the Cambria font? If not LaTeX has no other way to represent them

Comment: Please tell us which pdf viewer you employ. For what it's worth, I use Acrobat as my pdf viewer, and I don't experience any of the search-related problems you describe when compiling your sample document. I also use MacTeX2019, with all updates current, and the font file is `/Library/Fonts/Microsoft/Cambria.ttf`. The font file is said to contain 6974 [!] separate glyphs, including all of the "accented" characters employed in your sample document.

Comment: @Mico: Adobe reader DC, PDF xChange, Sumatra, all viewers are up tu date.